# Javascript for loop through array listing name and beginning letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'd like to loop through an array and show the name of each entry and if it's the first entry of a letter show the first letter as a grouping.

Desired result

```html
<h1>A</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Alligator</li>
            <li>Ant</li>
        </ul>
    <h1>B</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Bat</li>
            <li>Bear</li>
        </ul>
    <h1>K</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Kanagroo</li>
        </ul>
```

```js
var children = ['Kangaroo', 'Alligator', 'Ardvark', 'Ant', 'Bear', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Cow'];
            

            children.sort();

            var aZ = [];

            for (i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
              var child = children[i];
              
              aZ.push({
                name: child
              });
     
            }

            for (i=0; i < aZ.length; i++) {
              var child = aZ[i];  
              var cName = child.name; 
              var cLetter = cName.charAt(0); 
                
                document.write('<li>' + cLetter +'</li>'); 
                document.write('<li>' + cName +'</li>');    
            }
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I should go about accomplishing this?

Comment: `Any ideas what I'm doing wrong` - you're writing both cLetter and cName in an `<li>` - your desired output has the cLetter in a `<h1>` element. Try rewriting your javascript to match your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're putting it into another structure, seems unnecessary.

```
var children = ['Kangaroo', 'Alligator', 'Ardvark', 'Ant', 'Bear', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Cow'];
children.sort();

var char = '';
var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children[i];
    var cLetter = child.charAt(0);
    if (cLetter !== char) {
        if (output.length) output += '</ul>';
        output += '<h1>' + cLetter + '</h1><ul>';
        char = cLetter;
    }
    output += '<li>' + child + '</li>';
}
if (output.length) output += '</ul>';
document.write(output);
```

Comment: Good idea to build the entire markup string then use one *document.write*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
            var children = ['Kangaroo', 'Alligator', 'Ardvark', 'Ant', 'Bear', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Cow'];
            children.sort();

            var aZ = children.map(function(c){
                return { name : c};
            });

            var char = '';
            for (i=0; i < aZ.length; i++) {
              var child = aZ[i];  
              var cName = child.name; 
              var cLetter = cName.charAt(0); 
                if(cLetter === undefined || cLetter !== char){
                    if(cLetter)
                         document.write('</ul>'); 
                    document.write('<h1>' + cLetter +'</h1><ul>'); 
                    char = cLetter;
                }
                document.write('<li>' + cName +'</li>');    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make `aZ` an object, with the first letter as keys holding arrays of the names as the values.

```
var aZ = {};
```

Then iterate and create keys if they aren't already present, and in the same loop I'd make a map of the letters to be sorted later to get the order correct.

Then it's just a matter of iterating and creating proper elements

```js
var children = ['Kangaroo', 'Alligator', 'Ardvark', 'Ant', 'Bear', 'Bat', 'Cat', 'Cow'];
var aZ       = {};
var map      = [];
var html     = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children[i];
    var first = child.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

    if ( ! (first in aZ) ) aZ[first] = [];
    if ( map.indexOf(first) === -1 ) map.push(first);
    
    aZ[first].push(child);
}

map.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    var letter = map[i];
    var names  = aZ[letter];
    var h1     = document.createElement('h1');
    var ul     = document.createElement('ul');

    h1.innerHTML = letter;
    names.sort();
    
    for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = names[j];
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    
    html.appendChild(h1);
    html.appendChild(ul);
}

document.body.appendChild(html);
```

It's more code, and a lot more verbose and readable so it's easier to see what's going on.